# How to scrape non-tagged data with Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I wanted to try out web-scraping with Scrapy and picked the [link to the Wikipedia page for the Day January 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_1) as a generic example, I have no problem exstracting tags:

```
In [9]: response.css('div.mw-parser-output ul li a::text').getall()
```

Gives the following output:

```
Out[9]: ['153 BC',
 'Roman consuls',
 '[1]',
 '45 BC',
 'Julian calendar',
 '[2]',
 '42 BC',
 'Roman Senate',
 'deifies',
 'Julius Caesar',
 '[3]',
 '193',...]
```

However, I also want this text "Begin their year in office on Janurary 1",

[Im.(1): Here is the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Ch8.png)

Which, inspecting the HTML, does not appear to be part of any tag, being simply labled (text):

[Im.(2): The HMTL version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li0ED.png)

Is it possible to access that?

And while I am at it, is there an in-Scrapy way to concatenate the appropriate elements of the response such its first element - the zero index of events:

```
In [18]: events = response.css('div.mw-parser-output ul li a::text').getall()

In [19]: print(events[0])
Out [19]: 153 BC
```

Is the entire text seen in Im.(1), rather than just "153 BC"?

I was expecting that the (text) was attached to one of the a-tags ::text, but apparently it is not, and since it does not have any straight-forward tags, class, or any HMTL identifier. I am not sure how to proceed, any help would be much appriciated?

Comment: Share a sample of data that you'd like to see finally.

Answer (score 0):

The text you are seeking is part of the `li` element that is the parent of the `a` elements that you are currently extracting the text from.

This can all be easily extracted using an xpath expression such as:

```
In [18]: events = response.css('div.mw-parser-output ul li').xpath('.//text()').getall()
```

The above expressions should grab all of the text you are currently grabbing plus all of the text that you are not getting.